# Should jars have "provided" dependencies?

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, jar

We are building an ear that is going to run on a Websphere where j2ee.jar is provided.

Now we have the situation that an ejb (call it ejb.jar) depends on another jar (call it util.jar) which depends on j2ee.jar.

If mark j2ee.jar in the pom of util.jar as "provided", the ejb.jar won't build because provided is not transitive. If we mark it as "compile", it may become a compile dependency of the ear, unless we overwrite the scope.

What is the best approach? Should util.jar have provided dependencies, even if it is just a humble jar? Or should jars only have compile dependencies?

Comment: Assuming you are using an ecipse-based IDE, have you [added](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.wst.server.ui.doc.user%2Ftopics%2Ftwinstprf.html) a WebSphere or J2EE compliant runtime to the project?

Comment: I see you are building with maven, I think [this](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS8PJ7_9.0.0/com.ibm.etools.maven.doc/topics/localrepo.html) is the equivalent way of adding the associated runtime jars

Comment: @Lightbeard Thank you for your comments, but this is not about building in an IDE and it is also not about getting dependencies into the local repository. This is purely about the question how to construct poms in a useful and correct way if "provided" dependencies are used in transitive jars.

Comment: From [maven's docs](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html): "when building a web application for the Java Enterprise Edition, you would set the dependency on the Servlet API and related Java EE APIs to scope provided"

Comment: @Lightbeard Thank you, but I already knew that. I am talking about provided dependencies in jars (not in wars/ears, where they are obviously useful)

Comment: Sorry I can't be of more help. I used to work for WebSphere, but I've never used maven. I think our build guys would usually have the lib directory of websphere on the build box and build against that

Comment: @Lightbeard This is also not what the question is about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JARs can have provided dependencies... but the user having a dependency on it needs to make sure that this dependency is actually going to be provided at run-time. Since provided dependencies are not transitive, they also need to make sure that they do not depend on it for compilation; but if they do, the best practice would be to declare it explicitly with the compile (or provided) scope, and *not* rely on some form of transitivity (look at the [`analyze`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/analyze-mojo.html) goal of the Dependency Plugin, which, for example, lists used, but undeclared, dependencies).

- Provided dependencies in JARs can be useful when creating executable JARs. Consider the building of an uber-jar (a JAR with the classes all of its dependencies included in it): you may want to say that a specific dependency shouldn't end up in the uber-jar, because the container launching it will provide it at run-time.
- Also, a JAR may need a dependency to compile its code, but does not actually need it to run; as example, consider Maven plugins which declares [`maven-plugin-annotations` as a provided dependency](https://maven.apache.org/plugin-tools/maven-plugin-plugin/examples/using-annotations.html) because they only need the annotations to be built.
- Final point, there are JARs that have a good idea in which context they are going to be used: Spring WebMVC, for example, certainly depends on the Servlet API to compile, but at run-time, it knows it's going to be used in a Java EE context, and that the Servlet API will be provided by the Java EE server.

As a rule of thumb though, apart from the cases above, you probably don't want to have provided JAR dependencies inside of a JAR project: it should be up the client to decide whether some compile-time dependencies of yours are going to be provided for their specific case, and let the client override the scope. As a library writer, you don't really know how your library is going to be used.

In your specific case, since `ejb.jar` actually needs `j2ee.jar` to compile, it would be best to declare that dependency with the compile, or even with the provided scope in your case, regardless of what scope `util.jar` has set for `j2ee.jar`. (I'll note that it's weird for an utility JAR to have a dependency on what appears to be a JAR from Java EE web application classes.)